# CCDT fle configuration for multi queue channels- IBM MQ

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am new to the IBM MQ and I am doing research for one of the requirement. I have two MQ channels in the queue manager that I will be connecting from JMS client (Standalone Java Application) and I need to configure those in CCDT file.

When primary MQ channel that I am connected to is down, it has to connect to secondary standby MQ channel after waiting for certain amount of time while trying to reconnect to primary MQ channel.

Can I configure that wait time in CCDT file or in JMS client java class?

I have gone through the some of the IBM documentation and I see the `setCCDTURL()` and `setConnectionTimeout()` methods for factory object, I am not sure if that fulfills my requirement.

Comment: Do you want JMS to use MQ auto reconnect logic or will you be handling the reconnect?  Are the channel1 and channel2 on different servers (would you specify a different conname)?

Comment: @joshmc I am looking for options to implement wait time logic either in java code or CCDT file. Channel 1 and channel 2 are on different servers pointing to separate urls

Comment: There are various ways that built in reconnect works, one is that on a single channel (if the channel name is the same on both queue managers) you can specify a comma separated list of ip(port) [or dns(port)] entries.  MQ will try them in order even on the initial connection, if reconnect is enabled and required it will start at the first IP again on each reconnect attempt.  Reconnect will last a period of time the default is 30 minutes, during this time it will periodically try to reconnect.  Note if the qmgr name is different on the 2 different servers you will need to specify `QMNAME*`.

Comment: Another way is to have multiple entries in the CCDT with the QMNAME, again if the actual queue manager names are different pick a value to use that is the same across all channels you would specify `QMNAME*` to let me know it can connect to any queue manager listening on the destination server.  This would allow you to specify entries with different channel names.

Comment: In either case you would want to make sure the channel on the second server is not available if you don't want to connect to it when the primary is up.  In the CCDT if you use multiple entries you can add weights to have it prefer one channel over the other, if you have multiple names in the conname just put then in the order you want.

Comment: @JoshMc thanks for your inputs. In my case I have different queue managers with different channels. to configure reconnecttime on java side, Can I use setConnectionTimeout() to MQ factory object ? or Can we configure that in CCDT file.    And you mentioned we can add weights to prefer one over the other channel. can you please elaborate on that. how does that detect primary is up and is switched back from secondary. Can you please provide more information on that.